# Add parent and child categories from json to woocommerce via rest api

Tags: php, json, rest, woocommerce

please help me to solve the following problem:
from a third party vendor I get a JSON file of the following format:

```
[{   
                "SKU": "427515"
                "name": "Frame",
                "description": "18*23",
                "barcode": "6907000061885",
                "price": 356, 
                "category": "Frame",
                "full_category": "souvenirs and gifts"
                "box_length": 23,
                "box_width": 19,
                "box_height": 2, 
}]
```

where - full_category is the parent category and category - is the child category.
Then I import this JSON through a PHP script into woocomerce, the problem is that I do not understand how can I add a subcategory for the parent without categoryIDs?
the former store administrator left me the following script:

```
function createProducts()
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $products = getJsonFromFile();

    $imgCounter = 0;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        /*Chec sku before create the product */
        $productExist = checkProductBySku($product['sku']);       
        $categories = $product['categorias'];        
        $categoriesIds = array();     
        
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $categoriesIds[] = ['id' => getCategoryIdByName($category)];
        }
        $finalProduct = [
            'categories' => $categoriesIds,
        ];
       
    }
}
function createCategories()
{
    $categoryValues = getCategories();
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    
    foreach ($categoryValues as $value) {
        if (!checkCategoryByname($value)) {
            $data = [
                'name' => $value
            ];
            $woocommerce->post('products/categories', $data);
        }
    }
}
function checkCategoryByName($categoryName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $categories = $woocommerce->get('products/categories');
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['name'] === $categoryName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function getCategories()
{
    $products = getJsonFromFile();
    $categories = array_column($products, 'categorias');

    foreach ($categories as $categoryItems) {
        foreach ($categoryItems as $categoryValue) {
            $categoryPlainValues[] = $categoryValue;
        }
    }
    $categoryList = array_unique($categoryPlainValues);
    return $categoryList;
}
function getCategoryIdByName($categoryName)
{
    $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
    $categories = $woocommerce->get('products/categories');
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['name'] == $categoryName) {
            return $category['id'];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not very good at PHP can anyone tell me how I can change this to get parent and child categories from json above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the category ID, but if you know the name or slug, you can get it easily with [get_term_by](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/).  This returns a WP_Term object that contains the ID.

This will give you the category ID for the category named "news":

```php
$categoryId = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')->term_id;
```

In your script, assuming your variable `$category` is the category name, change this bit:

```php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoriesIds[] = ['id' => get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')->term_id];
}
```

to

```php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoriesIds[] = ['id' => get_term_by('name', $category, 'category')->term_id;
}
```

If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).